# Can multiple threads cause duplicate updates on constrained set?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

In postgres if I run the following statement

```
update table set col = 1 where col = 2
```

In the default [`READ COMMITTED` isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html), from multiple concurrent sessions, am I guaranteed that:

1. In a case of a single match only 1 thread will get a ROWCOUNT of 1 (meaning only one thread writes)
2. In a case of a multi match that only 1 thread will get a ROWCOUNT > 0 (meaning only one thread writes the batch)

Comment: Hope you don't mind the quick edit; wanted to get rid of the term "threads" because it's unsafe (libpq) or impossible (PgJDBC) to concurrently use multiple threads with one Pg connection. "concurrent sessions" seems safer.

Comment: @CraigRinger go for it! thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your stated guarantees apply in this simple case, but not necessarily in slightly more complex queries. See the end of the answer for examples.

### The simple case

Assuming that col1 is unique, has exactly one value "2", or has stable ordering so every `UPDATE` matches the same rows in the same order:

What'll happen for this query is that the threads will find the row with col=2 and all try to grab a write lock on that tuple. Exactly one of them will succeed. The others will block waiting for the first thread's transaction to commit.

That first tx will write, commit, and return a rowcount of 1. The commit will release the lock.

The other tx's will again try to grab the lock. One by one they'll succeed. Each transaction will in turn go through the following process:

- Obtain the write lock on the contested tuple.
- Re-check the `WHERE col=2` condition after getting the lock.
- The re-check will show that the condition no longer matches so the `UPDATE` will skip that row.
- The `UPDATE` has no other rows so it will report zero rows updated.
- Commit, releasing the lock for the next tx trying to get hold of it.

In this simple case the row-level locking and the condition re-check effectively serializes the updates. In more complex cases, not so much.

You can easily demonstrate this. Open say four psql sessions. In the first, lock the table with `BEGIN; LOCK TABLE test;`<sup>*</sup>. In the rest of the sessions run identical `UPDATE`s - they'll block on the table level lock. Now release the lock by `COMMIT`ting your first session. Watch them race. Only one will report a row count of 1, the others will report 0. This is easily automated and scripted for repetition and scaling up to more connections/threads.

To learn more, read [rules for concurrent writing](http://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/concurrency.pdf#page=11), page 11 of [PostgreSQL concurrency issues](http://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/concurrency.pdf) - and then read the rest of that presentation.

### And if col1 is non-unique?

As Kevin noted in the comments, if `col` isn't unique so you might match multiple rows, then different executions of the `UPDATE` could get different orderings. This can happen if they choose different plans (say one is a via a `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` and another is direct, or you're messing with the `enable_` GUCs) or if the plan they all use uses an unstable sort of equal values. If they get the rows in a different order then tx1 will lock one tuple, tx2 will lock another, then they'll each try to get locks on each others' already-locked tuples. PostgreSQL will abort one of them with a deadlock exception. This is yet another good reason why *all* your database code should *always* be prepared to retry transactions.

If you're careful to make sure concurrent `UPDATE`s always get the same rows in the same order you can still rely on the behaviour described in the first part of the answer.

Frustratingly, PostgreSQL doesn't offer `UPDATE ... ORDER BY` so ensuring that your updates always select the same rows in the same order isn't as simple as you might wish. A `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE ... ORDER BY` followed by a separate `UPDATE` is often safest.

### More complex queries, queuing systems

If you're doing queries with multiple phases, involving multiple tuples, or conditions other than equality you can get surprising results that differ from the results of a serial execution. In particular, concurrent runs of anything like:

```
UPDATE test SET col = 1 WHERE col = (SELECT t.col FROM test t ORDER BY t.col LIMIT 1);
```

or other efforts to build a simple "queue" system *will* *fail* to work how you expect. See the [PostgreSQL docs on concurrency](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/mvcc.html) and [this presentation](http://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/concurrency.pdf) for more info.

If you want a work queue backed by a database there are well-tested solutions that handle all the surprisingly complicated corner cases. One of the most popular is [PgQ](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SkyTools#PgQ). There's a useful [PgCon paper](http://www.pgcon.org/2008/schedule/events/79.en.html) on the topic, and [a Google search for 'postgresql queue'](http://google.com/?q=postgresql+queue) is full of useful results.

---

<sup>*</sup> *BTW, instead of a `LOCK TABLE` you can use `SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE col = 2 FOR UPDATE;` to obtain a write lock on just that on tuple. That'll block updates against it but not block writes to other tuples or block any reads. That allows you to simulate different kinds of concurrency issues.*

Comment: awesome answer, that LOCK trick is fantastic, the queue sample is fantastic

Comment: @SamSaffron Glad to help. Be aware when using artificial races set up by locks that, while they're really helpful, they can be misleading too. Every blocked tx starts at almost exactly the same time, so you don't necessarily catch concurrency issues that occur when there's slight (or big) stagger in the start times between concurrent jobs. It's worth doing scripted tests too.

Comment: ins serializable except for deadlock central, would the queue system work?

Comment: @SamSaffron At best, it'd work like a single thread of execution plus lots and lots and lots of serialization failures. Try it and see. If you want a queue, there are well established solutions. One is http://skytools.projects.postgresql.org/doc/pgq-sql.html; for others search SO and Google for 'postgresql queue'.

Comment: @SamSaffron I just tested. All but one of the tx's abort with serialization failures, pretty much how you'd expect. Setup with `delete from test; insert into test(col) select generate_series(0,100); begin; lock table test;`. Set up your competing workers with: `BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; UPDATE test SET col = 999999 WHERE col = (SELECT t.col FROM test t ORDER BY t.col LIMIT 1); COMMIT;`  . Then unlock by committing or rolling back in the 1st tx.

Comment: Yeah, queuing applications are clearly the worst case identified for the Serializable Snapshot Isolation techniques used for PostgreSQL 9.1 and later. One trivial quibble with Craig's first example is that if the concurrent `READ COMMITTED` queries choose different plans (e.g., one uses an index and one uses a table scan) two different concurrent queries could access the rows in a different order, which could result in deadlock or each updating some rows. That could be possible even with the simple example if one connection was using different costing factors. That would, in practice, be rare.

Comment: @kgrittn I'd like to claim that's why I added the "multiple rows" caveat, but I was just thinking about plans that use unstable sort methods. I'd actually foolishly assumed that the `col` in question was most likely unique.